# How to get the selected text inside a summernote editor?

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, summernote

I have 2 summernote editor in a page, which is a overview and content. In each editor, it has button that can get the selected text. How can I get the selected text when I click a button in its corresponding textarea editor?

Comment: Have have you tried so far?

Answer (score 7):

Use [createRange API](http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#createrange)

```
var range = $('#summernote').summernote('createRange')
range.toString() -> // your selected text
```

Comment: It just give me an (empty string)

Comment: I also just get an empty string. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Comment: This works fine you make sure you have some text selected in editor

Comment: can i get selected text with its formatting (with html)

Comment: worked like a charm  :) `const range = $('#summernote').summernote('createRange')?.toString()`